# Principal Component Analysis in C#

Tags: c#, .net, pca

It's pretty much all in the title: what library would you recommend to perform principal component analysis? I'm looking for free and simple to use - performance is not necessarily a criterion so far as I just want to play around with the concept and see what I get. Google got me this:

http://crsouza.blogspot.com/2009/09/principal-component-analysis-in-c.html

Anyone tried this? How good is it? Would you have any other recommendation?

Comment: Personally I'd use Matlab or something if I was just playing around. Trying to do mathematical stuff that you might not understand well can be hugely time consuming in any 'real' languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the help guys. I eventually decided to implement the algorithm myself, using Math.Net Numerics to lay the matrix groundwork and ARPACK to do the hard work of finding the biggest eigenvectors of the correlation matrix (I don't need of all them). Subject closed.

Comment: Can you please share you sample algorithm here? I want to convert 13D data to 2D/3D data for plotting in C#.

Answer (score 4):

I have used PCA in [SPSS](http://www.statisticshell.com/factor.pdf) and [Matlab](http://www.biospec.net/learning/matlab/matlab%20tutorial.pdf). This is a good place to start learning it, as those applications have already got all the infrastructure ready for you (like lots of plots and supportive tests).

If you are looking for something in C#, take a look at the [Accord framework](https://code.google.com/p/accord/) and maybe [this sample here](http://code.google.com/p/accord/wiki/SampleApp_PrincipalComponentAnalysis)